# How to split string a string that might contain multiple words

Tags: python

Trying to write a function that can decode morse code, and in case the input is a string containing multiple words I need them separate by a space (".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ." would translate in HEY JUDE), but my code is returning HEYJUDE.
Any ideas on how to fix this ?

```
def reverse(message):
    message = message.split()
    msg = ''
    for item in message:
        for k, v in MORSE_CODE_DICT.items():
            if v == item:
                msg += k
    print(msg)
```

Comment: `msg += k` is not adding spaces when joining the words. Also use `dict.get` instead of looping over your dictionary.

Comment: The Morse code string has 7 items but "HEY JUDE" has 8 so it appears the space is not part of the Morse code string so you have no way of knowing where to put a space.